# Lubuntu 12.04, need updates while roaming

Tags: 12.04, updates, lubuntu, intel-graphics

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 while I am roaming on old Dell Inspiron Pentium 4 with 1GB ram and integrated Ati graphics because I read that this distro handles 720p and more videos. Well, it looks like I was wrong because Mplayer keeps crashing. I started to think that if I update it may fix the problem. Okay, so I have data roaming but not tethering/hotspot, nor the money for it. Is there a way to download my updates to my phone (185MB approx.) then transfer to my laptop?

Comment: You might get better results asking a different question about your graphics problem with more details.

Comment: It's not the graphics. I am attempting to download the updates for Lubuntu 12.04 via 4g to my phone and then install manually to computer.

Comment: Also can you undo your edits. It appears you changed the purpose and reason for my question which was states in the last sentence. All information prior to the last sentence is pertinent.

Comment: Alright, it was potentially confusing because you were talking about two different problems. Will undo.

Comment: Thank you, sir. And, if you happen to know how to download the updates manually, I am happy to listen.

Comment: @karel Not exactly, he's looking at how to install all upgrades.

Comment: I still think you are asking the wrong question. 1. If you want to download all package it still will use some of your data plan. 2. The downloads are huge, is better if you try 13.10 and install that. 3. Mplayer doesn't crash just for the sake of it. Check the error logs and try to fix that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use... (drum roll)... **`apt-offline`!** You will need an Ubuntu live USB disk and another computer with internet access.

#### Step one is to install `apt-offline`.

Go to a computer with a working internet connection and download the [apt-offline package](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/88804602/apt-offline_1.1.1build1_all.deb). Save it to a pen drive. Alternately, save it to your phone (if possible), and transfer it to your PC.

Once the file is on your PC, double-click (unless you have click-to-select disabled) and install the `.deb`.

#### Step two is to create a package list

which you can do by opening a terminal and running `sudo apt-offline set ~/apt.sig`. this will create a file named `apt.sig` in your home folder. Copy it to your USB Live disk.

#### Step three is to obtain the packages

Boot from your live USB on a computer that has working internet access (e.g. at a library) and install `apt-offline`:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-offline
```

Then mount your USB drive, and use `apt-offline get --bundle /download/path/aptbundle.zip /path/to/apt.sig`, replacing `/path/to/apt.sig` with the path to `apt.sig` on your thumb drive.

#### Step four is to install the packages

Copy the created `.zip` file over to the offline PC. Right click and extract it in a new folder, open a terminal in that folder, and run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

**You will have to repeat this every couple of days *at least* if you want to keep your computer up to date with the latest security updates.**

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. The drum roll really did it for me. I was able to follow your instructions.